# Windows 7 hang on login screen after unlocking the workstation (after standby/hibernation)

Tags: windows-7, freeze, login, login-screen

I have a very annoying problem: Sometimes, Win7 on my laptop hangs on the login screen after unlocking the workstation when the computer is resumed from standby or hibernation. All I see then is this (and this screen sits there forever):

[image: Login screen hangs]

However, the system itself perfectly reacts: I can turn on/off the system (standby, hibernation), rotate the screen, change the volume, display brightness, turn on/off WiFi, Bluetooth, everything.
I assume the computer perfectly works but access to the desktop is denied due to the login screen which does not appear.

Unfortunately this is not really reproduceable, it happens maybe every 2-3 weeks. I would like to check if the computer is accessible via network (I am confident it would be!) but so far it always happened when I either had no network or did not know the IP address.

However, it is still crucial because so far all I could do is to turn it off completely to regain control, loosing much unsafed work already.

Also, I looked in the system logs but I did not find anything (e.g. that a service crashed).

In my opinion, GINA or some login service may have crashed. But this would be a serious bug then.

Comment: Is this computer part of a domain?  Do you have any drives mapped? What's the longest amount of time you've let it sit at that screen?

Comment: consider reviewing the programs that start at boot. There may be one that causes intermittent slowness. I use Sysinternals Autoruns to view startup items: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx Pay attention to whether this happens only on cold boot,, only on resume from hibernate, only when a network connection is not available, only when the system has previously been in heavy use (eg ram is quite full, which is definitely overhead when resuming), etc. MAke sure your harddisk and filesystem are in good shape, and always save your work before hibernating.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: No, no domain. Yes, drives mapped. It's sittering there forever, the longest time I've been waiting was 1/2 hour.

Comment: @FrankThomas: It should not have anything to do with boot because it happens when waking up from standby/hibernation. There is no pattern if it happens with/without network/power etc. Since really nothing is possible I assume it must be that GINA or so crashed. BTW: Nothing is in my system log

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me (several years in IT) like explorer has crashed.

If you can try pressing ctrl-alt-del, go to 'start task manager', then file -> new task (run...). Finally type "explorer.exe" in the box that comes up and press enter.

You say this is after login, and it happens every few weeks causing you to "loosing much unsafed work already."[sic]. I take it you mean logging in from when your computer was locked, not just starting up, as if it were starting up there would not be any unsaved work yet.

Given that, make sure you reboot every so often. Windows in my experience is not made for weeks+ of uptime, especially with unsaved work (also start saving your work periodically?...).

Comment: Unfortunately CTRL+ALT+DEL does not work, otherwise it would be trivial ;-) It is the login screen except that the input field disappeared. No access to the desktop at all! Yes, I need to clarify: It is not after login but after unlocking the PC (I'll edit the post). Sure I regularly safe my work but still my PC is heavily used over the day where I quickly open/close the lid for looking something up, noting something down (like a smartphone). IMO a behavior like this is still unacceptable for a mature OS and always saving work/excercising care can't be the (only) solution